# localize memoization inside a function in Julia

Tags: julia, memoization

Is there a way I can localize memoization (via Memoize.jl) inside a function? or at least delete the dictionaries created by memoization?

Clarification: suppose I define a define a function f(x, y). I want to start with a fresh table for every new value of y. That is, given y = y0, f( . , y0) iterates on itself for x, x-1, etc but given a new y = y1, I don't need to store the old table for y0, so that memory can be freed up. How can I do that?

Solution:

```
cachedfib() = begin
    global dict = Dict()
    global dict2 = Dict()
    function _fib(n::Int, a::Int)
        if !haskey(dict2, a)
            dict2[a] = true
            dict = Dict()
        end
        if haskey(dict, (n, a))
            return dict[(n, a)]
        elseif n < 2
            dict[(0, a)] = 0
            dict[(1, a)] = 1
            return dict[(n, a)]
        else
            dict[(n, a)] = a*(_fib(n - 1, a) + _fib(n - 2, a))
            return dict[(n, a)]
        end
    end
end
fib = cachedfib()

fib(10, 1)
fib(10, 2)
```

now call `dict` and `dict2` and check that the dictionaries are refreshed every time the second argument changes. You can get even better performance when the parameters to store are integers and you use `Array` instead of `Dict`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To use memoization technique you can do it with `let` or closures. Have a look at my rapid implementation of `factorial` (with closure).

```
with_cached_factorial() = begin
    local _cache = [1] #cache factorial(0)=1    
    function _factorial(n)          
        if n < length(_cache) 
            println("pull out from the cache factorial($n)=$(_cache[n+1])")
            _cache[n+1]
        else
            fres =  n * _factorial(n-1)
            push!(_cache, fres)
            println("put factorial($n)=$fres into the cache of the size=$(sizeof(_cache))") #a
            fres            
        end
    end 
end
```

Now, just use it:

```
julia> myf = with_cached_factorial()
_factorial (generic function with 1 method)

julia> myf(3)
pull out from the cache factorial(0)=1
put factorial(1)=1 into the cache of the size=16
put factorial(2)=2 into the cache of the size=24
put factorial(3)=6 into the cache of the size=32
6

julia> myf(5)
pull out from the cache factorial(3)=6
put factorial(4)=24 into the cache of the size=40
put factorial(5)=120 into the cache of the size=48
120

julia> myf(10)
pull out from the cache factorial(5)=120
put factorial(6)=720 into the cache of the size=56
put factorial(7)=5040 into the cache of the size=64
put factorial(8)=40320 into the cache of the size=72
put factorial(9)=362880 into the cache of the size=80
put factorial(10)=3628800 into the cache of the size=88
3628800
```

Comment: Thanks @maciek-leks, I tried using a `let` block like @tholy 's example but it doesn't seem to free memory after I run it, check my edit above.

Comment: @amrods, is it a rule of thumb of the memorization technique? I've edited my answer adding the size of of the cache. So, adding a new value into the cache increases the size of _factorial function with the value of new_cache_size-old_cache_size. IMHO whos() adds those binded variables size into the scope of a scoped function.

Comment: I see @maciek. But suppose, as in my case, that I define a function `f(x, y)`. I want to start with a fresh table for every new value of y. That is, given y = y0, f(. , y0) iterates on itself for x, x-1, etc but given a new y = y1, I don't need to store the old table for y0, so that memory can be freed up. How can I do that?

Comment: I hope I understood. So, the let block is quite dangerous because it creates a new scope every time the code is called. It is not an issue, but it is done on purpose to inject variables into functions i.e. in for-loops. So, I suggest to use closure and test if a new value of y comes. If so, recreate a cache by creating it. i.e. in my example let 't' plays the role of your 'y'. I would do it like that: "function _factorial(n, t=false)    
  if t
   _cache = [1]
  end
  if n < length(_cache)..."

Comment: thanks. I posted a minimal working example with your solution.

Comment: Does it work for you? I assume that global keyword is only for tracing these caching variables (dict, dict2)?

Comment: yes, I made them global to be able to see them later. I have a final question, albeit not related to this, how does julia know that where to "place the argument" after executing `myf = with_cached_factorial()` and calling `myf(n)`?

Comment: @amrods, calling with_cached_factorial it returns a function _factorial with one argument. The line "function _factorial(n)" inside with_cached_factorial is in fact the same as "return function _factorial(n)". Like in functional languages function is "first-class-object". It means that you can return it, like other things. So, that is why after invoking with_cached_factorial you have an access to _factorial function.

Comment: can a problem like this be parallelized?

Comment: Are you asking about either the factorial calculation or the memoization technique?

Comment: The memoization technique in a recursive context. I'm thinking that it can be challenging because you need to wait for a worker to finish the (n-1) iteration before you can start calculating the nth iteration, no?

Comment: If you can dispose of recursion it's OK, otherwise don't do it :) So, the memoization cache it is just a cache. Nothing special. So, if you can write serial version of your recursion algorithm - do it!

Answer (score 4):

```
let Aold = nothing
global foo
function foo(A::AbstractArray)
    if A == Aold
        println("Same as last array")
    else
        Aold = A
    end
    nothing
end
end
```

Results:

```
julia> A = rand(2,2)
2x2 Array{Float64,2}:
 0.272936  0.153311
 0.299549  0.703668

julia> B = rand(2,2)
2x2 Array{Float64,2}:
 0.6762    0.377428
 0.493344  0.240194

julia> foo(A)

julia> foo(A)
Same as last array

julia> foo(B)

julia> foo(A)

julia> foo(A)
Same as last array

julia> Aold
ERROR: UndefVarError: Aold not defined
```

Comment: Thanks @tholy, so all I need to do is wrap the function definition in `let`? I hadn't seen that construct before.

Comment: Can I use in some way Memoize.jl? it does not seem to work in the sense that the objects created by `@memoize` stay in memory...

Comment: This is independent of Memoize.jl.

Comment: If you want to use Memoize.jl, might be best to open an issue in that repository.